# Why does this stored proc cause a clustered index scan, but seek when using OPTION RECOMPILE?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, execution-plan, parameter, recompile

I think I may know the answer based on my research, but am looking for confirmation on how/why the engine compiles the plan the way it does with

Parameters being passed in:
@ID int
,@OtherID INT

```
SELECT  b.Column1
        ,b.Column2
        ,b.Column3
        ,b.Column4
        ,b.Column5
        ,c.Column1
        ,b.Column1
        ,e.Column1
FROM    Table1 AS b 
        inner join Table2 AS t
        on b.ID = t.ID
        left join [LINKED SERVER].[DB].dbo.Table3 as c
        on b.ID = c.ID
        left join Table4 AS e
        on b.ID= e.ID
where   (b.ID = @ID or @ID= 0)
        And b.ID = @OtherID
        And b.ID IS NOT NULL
        and e.ID = 1
```

Now I have determined that the cause of the index scan is because of this line: `where  (b.ID = @ID or @ID= 0)`. More specifically, @ID = 0.  To clarify even further, 0 for that ID field does not exist as a value in the underlying table, it was simply something a developer did to allow a user to pull back all of the results by passing in 0 to the parameter and then checking to see if that parameter is 0 so as a result more rows are pulled back (typically, you would just return 1-3 results).

Now, what is extremely odd, is that if I add `OPTION RECOMPILE`, the engine is able to create a much better plan at the cost of overhead (compilation time) of course:

[image]

What I would like to know is how is this possible.  From what I have read online, by using `OPTION RECOMPILE`, the engine will literally replace the value with the actual value passed into the parameter and it can very easily see that @ID 1234 does not equal 0.  However, if you don't use `OPTION RECOMPILE` the engine will take the total # of records, which is 120,000, and divide it by the total number of distinct possibilities, 107,000.  This comes out to about 1.1 estimated rows being returned and I confirmed this by looking at the estimated properties of the plan that has the index scan, but why would the engine continue to index scan if the estimation is correct?  I even updated stats just to be sure.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b.ID = @ID OR @ID = 0
```

The optimizer has to produce a plan with an index scan, because the plan is **cached and reused**.

On a subsequent execution, the parameter `@ID` might be zero. An index seek is of no value in that case, because there is no `ID` value to seek to. Other times, there will be a non-zero value provided for `@ID`, but the cached plan has to work correctly for all possible parameter values.

When `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is used, the *Parameter Embedding Optimization* (PEO) means the current value for `@ID` is used in place of the parameter on each execution, and no plan is cached.

Say `@ID` is 1234. After PEO, the optimizer sees:

```
b.ID = 1234 OR 1234 = 0
```

That is simplified by the contradiction detection logic to:

```
b.ID = 1234
```

...which enables a seek on `ID`.

For further reading please see my article [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options).

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicion.  As stated in my initial question, this is what I figured was happening behind-the-scenes.  However, I did not know it was called Parameter Embedding Optimization (PEO).  Appreciate the info!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is optional condition `(b.ID = @ID or @ID= 0)`

If you don't want to use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`, you should split your query on the condition:

```
IF @ID = 0 BEGIN
    SELECT b.Column1, 
           b.Column2, 
           b.Column3, 
           b.Column4, 
           b.Column5, 
           c.Column1, 
           b.Column1, 
           e.Column1
    FROM Table1 AS b
         INNER JOIN Table2 AS t ON b.ID = t.ID
         LEFT JOIN [LINKED SERVER].[DB].dbo.Table3 AS c ON b.ID = c.ID
         LEFT JOIN Table4 AS e ON b.ID = e.ID
    WHERE b.ID = @OtherID
          AND b.ID IS NOT NULL
          AND e.ID = 1;
END ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT b.Column1, 
           b.Column2, 
           b.Column3, 
           b.Column4, 
           b.Column5, 
           c.Column1, 
           b.Column1, 
           e.Column1
    FROM Table1 AS b
         INNER JOIN Table2 AS t ON b.ID = t.ID
         LEFT JOIN [LINKED SERVER].[DB].dbo.Table3 AS c ON b.ID = c.ID
         LEFT JOIN Table4 AS e ON b.ID = e.ID
    WHERE b.ID = @ID
          AND b.ID = @OtherID
          AND b.ID IS NOT NULL
          AND e.ID = 1;
END
```

Comment: I am aware of how to fix it, but I am really wanting to know why OPTION RECOMPILE is able to create the correct plan for what is seemingly a very simple query. The engine estimated 1 record being returned, so why is a scan operator chosen?  It should be smart enough to see that the parameter <> 0 very quickly?